# Use outputed layers directly in QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm tring to design a QGIS model in which I'm making iterations of the "join attributes by field value" algorithm (first image). However, I can't see how to directly use the output layer (named updated imput layer) as in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder (green objects, second image).

Is there a way?

[image: QGIS Modeler]

[image: Model builder in ArcGIS]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not very intuitive: You need to switch the input type from Model Input to Algorithm Output. Then you can select the output of another algorithm as input. See these images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help! I remember how I lost I was with this in the beginning. Please mark the question as solved :)